# Population VS Sample Standard Deviation

Tags: statistics, physics, mathematical-physics, average, standard-deviation

If I took multiple measurements of the length of a piece of material and wanted to find the average and standard deviation, would this be a population or sample standard deviation? I have looked all over the internet for an explanation between the two but am not having much luck.

Comment: To measure a population std dev. requires measuring every value in the "population". To compute the population standard deviation of heights of Americans, I'd need to know the height of every American. If you consider each measurement to have an error with some distribution, so that each measurement is a realization of a random variable, then your "population" is theoretical - all possible measurements. You cannot measure the population standard deviation. You can assume a particular distribution, with a particular population standard deviation, but you cannot measure the population std dev.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. So say I have to take the width of a rigid sticky note but I take only 3 measurements of the multiple different places to measure the width. This would be a sample since I am not taking every single measurement?

Comment: Yes. The only way to measure the population standard deviation would be if the population was finite, and you measured every value. Usually, if you have the population standard deviation, it's because you know the exact distribution (of your model), and you compute it from the distribution.

Comment: However, the sample standard deviation estimates the population standard deviation; the estimate gets better as the random sample gets larger.